# If $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ is $\mathcal C^1$ how can we know that a stationary point is an extremum?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ is $\mathcal C^1$ how can we know that a stationary point is an extremum ?

For example, for a function $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is $\mathcal C^1$ and $a$ is a stationary point, then $g$ has an extremum if the derivative change its sign.

Is there such a result for multiple variable function ?

Comment: Feel free to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: I know the test when f is $\mathcal C^2$ ! But here I can't compute the hessian !

Comment: Well, I see.  In this case there's no general strategy.  Would you give us a concrete example, please?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: The function is $f(x,y)=x^3-y^3+x^2+2xy+y^2$. It has no saddle point since there is no $\varepsilon>0$ s.t. $f(0,0)\in [f(0,\varepsilon),f(\varepsilon,0)]$, but how can I prove that there is an extremum or not at $(0,0)$ ? Thanks,

Comment: Notice that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: As the Hessian in the origin has eigenvalues $\pm2$, there's a saddle.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: The eigenvalue are $0$ and $4$, so it's a priori not a saddle point.